PostgreSQL recursive query join
In the query I shared below, I use 3 recursive loops to cumulatively retrieve debit, credit and budget values. Can I do this using 1 recursion instead of 3 recursions?
Also, can it be done in this format without changing the format of the query? Briefly, what I want to do in the query is to cumulatively reflect the debit, credit and budget (debit-credit) of the sub-account codes to a parent account for the account codes in accounting, and thus reflect the cumulative debit, credit and budget values ​​to the main account at the top.
select hkodu.id,
       hkodu.hesap_kodu           as hesapKodu,
       hkodu.hesap_adi            as hesapAdi,
       hkodu.parent_hesap_kodu_id as parentId,
       btc.butce_yili             as butceYili,
       hkodu.active               as active,
       hkodu.owner_birim_id       as birimId,
       (WITH recursive tree_hk AS (SELECT h.id, h.hesap_kodu, h.hesap_adi, h.parent_hesap_kodu_id, b.borc, b.alacak
                                   FROM hesap_kodu h
                                            JOIN butce b ON h.id = b.hesap_kodu_id
                                   where h.id = hkodu.id
                                     and h.active = true

                                   UNION ALL

                                   SELECT hk.id,
                                          hk.hesap_kodu,
                                          hk.hesap_adi,
                                          hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id,
                                          bc.borc,
                                          bc.alacak
                                   FROM hesap_kodu hk
                                            JOIN butce bc ON hk.id = bc.hesap_kodu_id
                                            JOIN tree_hk tr ON tr.id = hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id
                                   where hk.active = true)

        select sum(borc - alacak)
        from tree_hk)             as butce,

       (WITH recursive tree_hk AS (SELECT h.id, h.hesap_kodu, h.hesap_adi, h.parent_hesap_kodu_id, b.borc, b.alacak
                                   FROM hesap_kodu h
                                            JOIN butce b ON h.id = b.hesap_kodu_id
                                   where h.id = hkodu.id
                                     and h.active = true

                                   UNION ALL

                                   SELECT hk.id,
                                          hk.hesap_kodu,
                                          hk.hesap_adi,
                                          hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id,
                                          bc.borc,
                                          bc.alacak
                                   FROM hesap_kodu hk
                                            JOIN butce bc ON hk.id = bc.hesap_kodu_id
                                            JOIN tree_hk tr ON tr.id = hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id
                                   where hk.active = true)

        select sum(alacak)
        from tree_hk)             as alacak,
       (WITH recursive tree_hk AS (SELECT h.id, h.hesap_kodu, h.hesap_adi, h.parent_hesap_kodu_id, b.borc, b.alacak
                                   FROM hesap_kodu h
                                            JOIN butce b ON h.id = b.hesap_kodu_id
                                   where h.id = hkodu.id
                                     and h.active = true

                                   UNION ALL

                                   SELECT hk.id,
                                          hk.hesap_kodu,
                                          hk.hesap_adi,
                                          hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id,
                                          bc.borc,
                                          bc.alacak
                                   FROM hesap_kodu hk
                                            JOIN butce bc ON hk.id = bc.hesap_kodu_id
                                            JOIN tree_hk tr ON tr.id = hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id
                                   where hk.active = true)

        select sum(borc)
        from tree_hk)             as borc

from hesap_kodu hkodu
         left join butce btc on btc.hesap_kodu_id = hkodu.id;


Sure, you need only to call it once and than canrefer to it as often as you need
WITH recursive tree_hk AS (
SELECT h.id, h.hesap_kodu, h.hesap_adi, h.parent_hesap_kodu_id, b.borc, b.alacak
   FROM hesap_kodu h
            JOIN butce b ON h.id = b.hesap_kodu_id
   where h.active = true

   UNION ALL

   SELECT hk.id,
          hk.hesap_kodu,
          hk.hesap_adi,
          hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id,
          bc.borc,
          bc.alacak
   FROM hesap_kodu hk
            JOIN butce bc ON hk.id = bc.hesap_kodu_id
            JOIN tree_hk tr ON tr.id = hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id
   where hk.active = true)
select hkodu.id,
       hkodu.hesap_kodu           as hesapKodu,
       hkodu.hesap_adi            as hesapAdi,
       hkodu.parent_hesap_kodu_id as parentId,
       btc.butce_yili             as butceYili,
       hkodu.active               as active,
       hkodu.owner_birim_id       as birimId,
       (select sum(borc - alacak)
        from tree_hk
 WHERE id = hkodu.id)             as butce,

       (

        select sum(alacak)
        from tree_hk
 WHERE id = hkodu.id)             as alacak,
       (select sum(borc)
        from tree_hk
 WHERE id = hkodu.id)             as borc

from hesap_kodu hkodu
         left join butce btc on btc.hesap_kodu_id = hkodu.id;


I think the condition h.id = hkodu.id will result in an error, as hkodu is not defined at that place now..
It should be moved into the SELECT SUM(<whatever>) FROM tree_hk th (I added an alias) parts as an added WHERE th.id = hkodu.id, I believe

yes you are right, i corrected it

Unfortunately, when I try this way, the budget, debit and receivable values ​​are not cumulatively collected correctly. Do you know of another method?

Please add tables and data to your question ideally as dB fiddle or dml

Without some sample data and expected result it is hard to tell, but maybe you could get it without recursions. If it is possible to make correct partition by and order by in Sum() Over() analytic function with windowing clause - then it would look something like below. Think that in postgres windowing clause (Rows Between/Range)  could be ommited as it defaults to all preceding till current row.
Once again, not sure, but might be worth to try - it's up to you.
select  hkodu.id,
        hkodu.hesap_kodu           as hesapKodu,
        hkodu.hesap_adi            as hesapAdi,
        hkodu.parent_hesap_kodu_id as parentId,
        btc.butce_yili             as butceYili,
        hkodu.active               as active,
        hkodu.owner_birim_id       as birimId,
    --
        Sum(Coalesce(btc.borc, 0)) 
                Over(Partition By hkodu.hesap_kodu, hkodu.hesap_adi, hkodu.parent_hesap_kodu_id
                     Order By hkodu.id
                     Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) 
        - Sum(Coalesce(btc.alacak, 0) 
                Over(Partition By hkodu.hesap_kodu, hkodu.hesap_adi, hkodu.parent_hesap_kodu_id
                     Order By hkodu.id
                     Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as butce
    --
        Sum(Coalesce(btc.alacak, 0) 
                Over(Partition By hkodu.hesap_kodu, hkodu.hesap_adi, hkodu.parent_hesap_kodu_id
                     Order By hkodu.id
                     Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as alacak,
    --
        Sum(Coalesce(btc.borc, 0)) 
                Over(Partition By hkodu.hesap_kodu, hkodu.hesap_adi, hkodu.parent_hesap_kodu_id
                     Order By hkodu.id
                     Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as borc               
from       hesap_kodu hkodu
left join  butce btc on btc.hesap_kodu_id = hkodu.id
where      hkodu.active = true

